# Why is chrome stepping into ignored files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to step through a single file, but the debugger keeps stepping through miscellaneous/third party js scripts. I have them added in my ignore list, it even says "This script is on the debuggers ignore list", but it still steps through them.

What is the point of having an ignore list if chrome still steps through them?

Is there any way that I can just step through the file that I want to step through? Debugging is a nightmare when I have to step through dozens of misc files.

Comment: Chrome and edge both. Angular development with mapping turned on.

Comment: did you ever figure out why? this is driving me nuts.

Comment: SAME problem here!  This is still very much an issue as of Nov 2023.

Windows 11 Pro 23H2
Chrome Version 119.0.6045.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)
uBlock Origin (subscriber.js)
WakaTimje (wakatimeScript.js)