# Avoid irrelevant files while debugging in Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While debugging in Chrome I want to avoid jumping through content scripts and libraries, so I enabled ignoring such files in preferences as per documentation but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried patterns, "ignore content scripts" checkbox, right-click on the file, etc.
Weirdly enough it shows all the files I didn't want to go through, with the message that the file is in the ignore list:

[image]

How to effectively ignore those?

Comment: Same question, no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68424845/why-is-chrome-stepping-into-ignored-files

Comment: Could you use conditional breakpoints instead? If you know the code your debugging, you should be able to predictably debug code using conditional breakpoints

Comment: SAME problem here.  This is still very much an issue as of Nov 2023.

Windows 11 Pro 23H2
Chrome Version 119.0.6045.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)
uBlock Origin (subscriber.js)
WakaTimje (wakatimeScript.js)

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox didn't work for me either. So what I did was I let it step into the script I didn't want. Then I right clicked it in the call stack and clicked "add to ignore list".

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me either :\

Answer (score 0):

Although it should work - and sometimes does - right mouse clicking on the source panel code **seems to not work**....

[image: ![enter image description here]

But right mouse clicking on a source URL from the Sources/Page list on the left of the Sources panel **DOES seem to work**....

[image]